# can some one explain communication between two clients in below network?

Tags: networking, switch-statement, ip, mac-address

PC1 -> switch A -> switch B -> PC2.

Ip address of PC1 -192.168.2.1
Ip address of PC2 -192.168.2.2

if i ping PC2 from PC1, how will be the packet forwarded?

what will be the packets source ip address, destination ip address, source mac address and destination mac address at port connecting to PC1 and at port connecting to PC2 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can omit switches between hosts, because they don't affect or modify any communication between hosts. They just store informations about what MAC address is reachable at what interface to reduce spamming network segments with useless data. Whole communication will be done in few steps:

1. PC1 want to send ICMP packet to PC2, but don't know his MAC address yet
2. **network:**: PC1: ARP - what is address of 192.168.2.2?
3. **network:**: PC2: ARP - address of 192.168.2.2 is aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
4. PC1 has now L2 address, it can send packet
5. **network:**: PC1: ICMP echo-request - src-mac: 11:22:33:44:55:66, src-ip: 192.168.2.1 ... dest-mac: aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff, dest-ip: 192.168.2.2
6. PC2 recieves ICMP echo-request, and want to send echo-reply, but don't know L2 address of 192.168.2.1
7. **network:** PC2: ARP - what is address of 192.168.2.1?
8. **network:** PC1: ARP - address of 192.168.2.1 is 11:22:33:44:55:66
9. **network:** PC2: ICMP echo-reply - src-mac: aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff, src-ip: 192.168.2.2 ... dest-mac: 11:22:33:44:55:66, dest-ip: 192.168.2.1